# Windows File Permissions

Tags: windows

RE: Windows Server 2003. Windows7 Clients.
What I need to achieve is this:
Staff need to be able to submit documents/files via **'Save as'** in a network location.
Staff **cannot** 'browse' to this location to copy or view files through **'My Computer'**
Any hints on what special permissions would be great.
Thanks in advance.
J

Comment: So you want a drop-box type effect, where they can drop files (or create them, with Save As), without being able to see the contents of the folder? How do you solve for files that have the same name?

Comment: There's no built-in way to do this.  Instead, create a folder for each staff member, with permissions for only that person and whoever it is who is to collect the files.

Answer (score 0):

Since some time I don't have any windows server but if I remember well, you can assign a group `Write` permission to a folder and remove (untick) `modify` and `read`. This way users will only be able to write, not read and modify existing files (they will only create new files).

Thanks to Soandos comment, the users will be able to see the filenames (but not reading the files). If you want to hide the filenames too, you can make a sub-directory in the share to place the files and they won't be able to see the filenames (as they won't be able to open the subdirectory for reading).

Comment: I think it requires some clarification from the OP. It would seem that this would work, but employees would be able to see all the files names. Not sure if that matters